# shaft speed when 2 motor connected

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical

I have motor 1 1000 which rpm & motor 2 which 1500 rpm connected with shaft via gear ratio of 1:2 and what will be the shaft speed ? how can i calculate shaft speed?

I am considering the shaft gear ratio as 3 ,then what will be the speed of shaft ?

the shaft speed will be combined speed of 2 motor ?
or it will be maximum speed of any of this motor ?

i am looking for suggestion to make a model to simulate

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (whether or not it is actual homework). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

If you couple together two motors of unequal speed through a gear system which allows the faster motor to match speed with the slower one, then the rotating speed will equal that of the slower one and their torque outputs will add.

If you couple them in a manner where their output speeds do not match, then the more powerful motor will drive the other one in reverse and their torque outputs will subtract.

It is not advisable to couple together motors whose operating speeds are different.